# Import data into wordpress with parent child relationships?

Tags: xml, wordpress, csv, import

I would like to achieve the following:

Imagine I have a xml like this(or the same as .csv):

```
<Node>
    <Page>
        <Id>123123</Id>
        <Name>Test</Name>
    </Page>
</Node>
<Structure>
    <ParentPage>Test</ParentPage>
</Structure>
```

I hope you get the picture. Now this "Page", should be the child of "Parent Page", the only problem is, that I don't have the ParentId. Is it possible to do that?

I hope this is not a basic task, as I just didn't really know how to search for this specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reading the XML and then using it to create these pages, you're likely using `wp_insert_post()` to create the pages, no? If so, that returns the ID of the post/page it creates which you can then use when creating the child page. Something like this:

```
$parent_id = wp_insert_post( array(
  // your arguments for the parent page
) );

$child_id = wp_insert_post( array(
  'post_parent' => $parent_id,
  // your arguments for the child page
) );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: You are right. I did it with the returning ID and then I passed that parent ID to the function to insert all those pages recursively